# Working out costs to implement WCAG 2.0 (AA) site

Tags: cms

I've run our client's site through a WCAG 2.0 validator which has returned 415 tasks that need to be worked through in order to get it WCAG 2.0 compliant.

For the most part, I can get a rough estimation of how long a task will take but there are tasks I have never had to do before which I am not sure how to cost.

I would like to know if someone has a rough guide on what to cost a client to convert their site to a compliant WCAG 2.0 (AA) site.

Comment: What are the tasks that you are having trouble costing?

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The first factor for me depends on how and why you are involved - are you being asked to fix errors on a site you built, or are you being brought in to fix what essentially sounds like someone elses mess?

As you have used the tag "cms" but not specified which cms it is, it might be worth noting that some of the warnings/errors might not be able to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

With stuff like this I have always given a high price based on my hourly rate and tell them that this is an estimate, it make take more time or less time. If it's less then bill them less, if it's going to be more let them know ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kel. It's just that initial costing. Never done something like this before so it's a bit difficult knowing what to charge but I will go on your recommendation.

Cheers!

Comment: I would recommend that you make a comment on kel's answer rather than posting another answer. Honest mistake :)